# python request and MSL is not working with azure protected URL

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

i have some url where i need to do web crawling and it is protected by azure SAML protected.
i have got the access token but still, request.get method return me to the redirected SAML login page content i use python masl library for azure SAML authentication.

```
import requests
http_proxy = "http://my proxy setting here"
https_proxy = "http://my proxy setting here"
proxyDict = {
"http": http_proxy,
"https": https_proxy,
}
app = ConfidentialClientApplication(
"my azure client id here",
"my azure sceret id here",
authority="https://login.microsoftonline.com/my tenat id here", proxies=proxyDict)
user = 'myuser@hotmail.com'
pwd = 'mypassword'
scope=['User.Read']
access_token = app.acquire_token_by_username_password(username=user, password=pwd, 
 scopes=scope)
url = 'https://my web site where i need to do crawling'
api_head = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token['access_token']}
response = requests.get(url, proxies=proxyDict, headers=api_head)
```

but in return i get the login page url content only not the page i requested.
also if i try to use some Microsoft graph that work fine and return the data.
Not sure what is wrong in this flow any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: What is the website URL which you want to crawl?

Comment: The token would normally be passed through a cookie.  Verify the `'Authorization': 'Bearer ' `  is the proper name and format for the cookie.

Comment: Check via a request on browser that the header has exactly the same dictionary that you are providing.
It is also possible that the authentication is not happening by the token and the application requires the credentials in the request itself in string format (though this would be bad practice on part of the application developer). In that case you could try HTTPBasicAuth from here https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/authentication/

Comment: HTTPBasicAuth is not working here as this is azure SAML protected application

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure the `acquire_token_by_username_password` method handles expired token: `if token.is_expired: token.refresh()`
2. You get access token without proxy, but request private address with proxy.